# Access denied to my XML file while running the executable

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a xml file in the app's base directory, but can't access it for reading from or writing to.
This is the error message I get:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\MyProject\MyApp\ProjectsData.xml' is denied.

> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>
> at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)

> at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)

> at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)

> at MyApp.Form1.LoadProductID(String ProductID)base

Could somebody please point me in the right direction?
Thank you.

Comment: Is 'ProjectsData.xml' in 'C:\Program Files\MyProject\MyApp'?  Have you checked the permissions for  'C:\Program Files\MyProject\MyApp'?

Comment: `%ProgramFiles%` and `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` isn't the correct location for your data. Because of this, MS has restricted access to files/folders in these locations.

Comment: @dbasnett The folder has read-only permission for all its files, including for ProjectsData.xml, which is located there at installation time. Is there a way to set different permissions in the installer?

Comment: @user9938 I assume this is the default setting. Is there a way to set different permissions in the installer?

Comment: c:\Program Files can only be written by an ADMIN.